# CUDA C++: Using a template function which calls a template kernel

Tags: c++, linux, templates, cuda

I have a class which has a template function.  This function calls a template kernel.  I'm doing my development in Nsight on a Linux box.  In doing this, I encounter the following pair of conflicting requirements:

1 - When implementing a template function, the definition must appear in the *.h (or *.cu.h) file since the code is not generated until the template is needed.

2 - Kernel code must appear in the *.cu, since the compiler is not able to recognize the <<< and >>> tokens when they are in the header file.

I think there is probably a way to get around the second one with a little compiler voodoo.

When I set up the system where the template member function is in the *.cu.h file, I get the following compiler errors:

error: expected primary-expression before '<' token

error: expected primary-expression before '>' token

This seems indicative that it is parsing the << and then the >> tokens and not recognizing the <<< or >>> tokens.

An general outline of structure of the pertinent parts of the code is below:

In MyClass.cu.h:

```
#include "MyKernels.cu.h"

class MyClass{
    template <typename T> void myFunction(T* param1, int param2);
};

template <typename T> void myFunction(T* param1, int param2){
    blocks = 16;
    blockSize = 512;
    myKernel<<<blocks, bockSize>>>(d_param1, param2);
}
```

In MyKernels.cu.h:

```
#ifndef MYKERNELS_H_
#define MYKERNELS_H_

template <typename T>
extern __global__ void myKernel(T* param1, int param2);
#endif
```

In MyKernels.cu:

```
#include "MyKernels.cu.h"

template<typename T>
__global__ void myKernel(T* param1, int param2){
    //Do stuff
}
```

**Edit 7/31/2015:**
To make the structure of what I am trying to accomplish a little more clear, I have written a small demonstrative project.  It is posted publicly on github at the following URL:

https://github.com/nvparrish/CudaTemplateProblem

Comment: I wonder what is the point adding tag for a different language not related to a question?

Comment: which CUDA version are you using?

Comment: You haven't passed any template arguments anywhere I can see. Also, what is getMax?

Comment: are you actually compiling using `nvcc`?

Comment: @talonmies The earlier declaration of getMax() should have read myKernel().  I have edited the code to return to consistency.

Comment: @m.s. The compiler is using nvcc (/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc) for all the code.  I have tried to simplify my question to only the pertinent parts.  I have already used my code to do successfully perform some basic CUDA tasks so the basic setup is sound.

Comment: Of course your posted code has no `main` function, for example.  Presumably that is in some other file, probably a .cpp file.  When you include the posted `MyKernels.cu.h` in a .cpp file in your project, that will be handled by the regular host compiler (even if you are compiling it with `nvcc`) and the host compiler will choke on the kernel launch syntax (`<<<...>>>`) just as you have indicated in your question.  This is the reason for the pointed question by @m.s "are you actually compiling using nvcc" A more complete representation of what you are doing might be better to avoid this churn.

Comment: In your header file, in the template function definition, you could just call a wrapper function (could even be templated) rather than the `myKernel` itself.  Then in MyKernels.cu you could define the wrapper function, and have it call the kernel.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have tried to provide wrapper functions for the kernel calls, but I run into the same problem.  The wrappers are template functions which need to be in the *.cu.h header, but they, in turn, call kernel functions, which use the triple-chevron, which isn't properly parsed in the *.cu.h.  I think I will try to create a very simple project so that I can provide a full set of simple code to illustrate the problem more completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper function declaration needs to be in the header file.  The function definition does not.

Here is what I had in mind:

```
$ cat MyClass.cuh
template <typename T> void kernel_wrapper(T*, int);
class MyClass{
  public:
    template <typename T> void myFunction(T* param1, int param2);
};

template <typename T> void MyClass::myFunction(T* param1, int param2){
    kernel_wrapper(param1, param2);
}
$ cat MyKernels.cu
#include "MyClass.cuh"
#define nTPB 256

template <typename T>
__global__ void myKernel(T* param1, int param2){

  int i = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (i < param2){
    param1[i] += (T)param2;
  }
}

template <typename T>
void kernel_wrapper(T* param1, int param2){
  myKernel<<<(param2+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(param1, param2);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

template void MyClass::myFunction(float *, int);
template void MyClass::myFunction(int *, int);

$ cat mymain.cpp
#include "MyClass.cuh"

int main(){

  MyClass A;
  float *fdata;
  int *idata, size;
  A.myFunction(fdata, size);
  A.myFunction(idata, size);
}

$ nvcc -c MyKernels.cu
$ g++ -o test mymain.cpp MyKernels.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
$
```

Note the forced template instantiation.  This will be necessary if you want a template specialization to occur in one compilation unit (a .cu file, where kernel definitions belong), so it is usable in another compilation unit (a .cpp file, which does not understand cuda syntax).

Comment: The real key was the very end.

"Note the forced template instantiation. This will be necessary if you want a template specialization to occur in one compilation unit (a .cu file, where kernel definitions belong), so it is usable in another compilation unit (a .cpp file, which does not understand cuda syntax)."

Once I added a section like

    "template void MyClass::myFunction(float *, int);"

it was able to resolve.  Thanks!